How can one efficiently construct an SQL query that includes multiple UNION operations?
I wish to construct a query involving multiple unions.
select * from (
(select cols from a)
union (select cols from b)
union (select cols from c)
union (select cols from d)
...)

I intend to reduce redundancy by employing include statements and utilize properties for table name transmission. Additionally, I plan to employ trim to eliminate superfluous unions in the outer layer.
<sql id="unionSql">
    union (select cols from ${tableName})
</sql>
<select id="testSql">
select cols from (
<trim prefixOverrides="union ">
    <include refid="unionSql">
        <property name="tableName" value="a"/>
    </include>
    <include refid="unionSql">
        <property name="tableName" value="b"/>
    </include>
    <include refid="unionSql">
        <property name="tableName" value="c"/>
    </include>
    ...
</trim>)
</select>

However, I have encountered an issue where the prefixOverrides in the outer layer are not functioning as expected.
select * from (
union (select cols from a)
union (select cols from b)
union (select cols from c)
union (select cols from d)
...)

Upon examining an issue on GitHub, I discovered that the parsing of nodes occurs from the outside inward, which has provided me with a plausible understanding of why my prefixOverrides are ineffective.
Nevertheless, I am now questioning whether the if node can be properly trimmed, as I am uncertain if it operates before or after the trim function.
Apart from the method of removing unions in the first statement, are there any more concise approaches to constructing this query?

It should work. You can try this portable demo yourself. <include> is resolved when the XML file is read, so the parsing order does not matter here.

Thank you. Through your guidance, I discovered an error in my code—specifically, I mistakenly used "Enter" instead of "Space" after "union". However, I’m curious to know how I could detect the use of "Enter" if I were to employ it intentionally.

Glad to hear the problem is resolved ️
Do you know which character your Enter key inputs? It usually inserts a new line, so it should be obvious (it might depend on the editor you use).
As a general tip, IDEs and many developer-friendly editors have 'show control/special characters' option that may help you find the anomaly.

I’m using JetBrains IDEA as my IDE, with file encoding set to UTF-8. I’ve checked, and the line separator is LF (\n). How can I effectively match this? I just tried using prefixOverrides="union\n ", but it didn’t work.

As it's XML, you need to use character reference i.e. prefixOverrides="union&#10;".
Also, as explained in the doc, you can specify multiple patterns e.g. prefixOverrides="union&#10;|union ".

I am profoundly grateful for your response. I will consolidate the questions to assist a broader audience.

This example functions as intended; however, when applying it in practice, it is crucial to verify whether a space immediately follows your union. Should other symbols be employed, they must be represented within the prefixOverrides.

In this instance, I inadvertently pressed Enter instead of space, causing the matching process to fail. Furthermore, special characters used within XML necessitate encoding transformations. The encoding for a line feed (LF) newline is &#10; (different file formats or systems may utilize distinct newline characters).
Encoding for additional characters can be referenced at List of Unicode Characters.

